# NSImageView is too slow

Tags: macos, performance, cocoa

I'm developing a macOS Cocoa application that is an Image viewer, like Preview.app.

When I try to load a 6000x4000 JPEG with `NSImageView`, my application is too slow.

There is an `NSImageView` in an `NSScrollview` to support magnification.

How can I speed up and optimize my app for zooming into high resolution images?

Answer (score 1):

use a CATiledLayer - there is no ready made view provided out of the box BUT im sure there are samples and maybe opensource controls.

e.g. see: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/